# Count number of child in each level PHP

Tags: php, count, tree

I have a function which prints categories in a tree structure. I need to find how many subcategories there are for each category.

An example, with subcategory count given in bracket:

```
a (3)
  -a1 (0)
  -a2 (1)
    -a21 (0)
b (3)
  -b1 (2)
    -b11 (1)
      -b111 (0)
```

The following function prints the structure, but how can I get the count?

`$parent` - root id
`$category` - list of all ids

```
function buildCategory($parent, $category) {
        $html = "";
        global $i;
         if (isset($category['ereferencecodes'][$parent])) {
            $html .= "<ul>\n";
            foreach ($category['ereferencecodes'][$parent] as $cat_id) {

                if (!isset($category['ereferencecodes'][$cat_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li>\n" . $category['referencecodes'][$cat_id]['userName']."(".$category['referencecodes'][$cat_id]['userMobileno'].")". "</a>\n</li> \n";  $i++;}
                if (isset($category['ereferencecodes'][$cat_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li>\n" . $category['referencecodes'][$cat_id]['userName'] . "(".$category['referencecodes'][$cat_id]['userMobileno'].")"."</a> \n";
                    $result= buildCategory($cat_id, $category);
                    $html.=$result[0];
                    $html .= "</li> \n"; $i++;
               }
            }
            //$i =sizeof($category)+1;
            $html .= "</ul> \n";
        }

        //return array($html,$i);
            $result = array($html,$i);
            return $result;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't take the time to understand your code but..

Comment: You could try something with [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) using `COUNT_RECURSIVE`.